# How can I center the text inside each cell in a table vertically?

Tags: tables

I am trying to vertically center the text inside the Position and Person(s) headings but I can't really do it. I want them to be as denoted in the picture (vertically centered).
My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{3in}|}
        \hline
        Position          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Person(s)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Role} \\ \hline
        Co-head &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Islam Mahdy\\ Youssef Amr\end{tabular} &
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Reviewing the content of each session previously.  
            \item Reviewing the progression of the academic sessions whether they for the Curriculum sessions or the standardized tests' sessions.
            \item Having continuous check on the magazine to ensure the conformity of the topics discussed to the club's goal  
        \end{itemize}    \\ \hline
        Vice head &
        Ahmed Magdy &
    loremipsum \\ \hline
        Head of Academics & Mohamed Badr                   &                           \begin{itemize}
            \item Preparing the content of each session.  
            \item Managing the time table of the weekly-held sessions.
            \item Conducting mini quizzes each week to make sure the students have comprehended the previous session.   
        \end{itemize}           \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Magazine} &
        \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ali Ashraf \\ Ahmed Hamed\end{tabular}} &
        \multirow{2}{*}{sdsdsdsds} \\
        &                                &                                    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: The table from the code above]

Comment: You can use a `m` type column instead of the `p` type column.

Comment: @leandriis it didn't work, gives me a lot of errors

Comment: Do you load the `array` package in your preamble? If not, add it.

Comment: Is it \usepackage{array} or something else?

Comment: Yes. than should at least make the code compilable when using the `m` type column. There are however some more adjustments that I would suggest. I will add a more in-depth answer addressing them as well.

Comment: It worked thanks! I am waiting for your suggestions anyway

Answer (score 5):

In addition to vertically centering the contents of the table, I have also implemented the following changes in the below MWE:

- Used `tabularx` in order to make sure, the table fits into the textwidth. In the original example, it was a lot wider than the textwidth. You got an voerfull box warning informing you about that.
- In order to vertically center the contents, I have added `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}`. Originally, the `X` type column is derived from the `p` type column and therefore aligns ist contents just as in your original example. The above line now redefindes the `X` type column to act like a vertically centered `m` type column. (There is no need to explicitly add the `array` package here, since `tabularx` already loads it.)
- I have added the `makecell` package in order to replace the nested tabulars and the multicolumns in the column headers.
- I have removed the `\multirow` commands in the last table row, as well as the empty row there.
- I have added the `enumitem` package and defined a new customized `tabenum` environment for the use in tables. This environment saves you quite a lot of space above, below and on the left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{multirow} % no longer needed
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[tabitem,1]{label*=\textbullet,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    nosep,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                    after=\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
    \hline
    \thead{Position} 
      & \thead{Person(s)} 
        & \thead{Role} \\
    \hline
    Co-head 
      & \makecell{Islam Mahdy\\ Youssef Amr} 
        & \begin{tabitem}
            \item Reviewing the content of each session previously.  
            \item Reviewing the progression of the academic sessions whether they for the Curriculum sessions or the standardized tests' sessions.
            \item Having continuous check on the magazine to ensure the conformity of the topics discussed to the club's goal  
          \end{tabitem}    \\ 
    \hline
    Vice head 
      & Ahmed Magdy 
        & loremipsum \\ 
    \hline
    Head of Academics 
      & Mohamed Badr 
        &  \begin{tabitem}
             \item Preparing the content of each session.  
             \item Managing the time table of the weekly-held sessions.
             \item Conducting mini quizzes each week to make sure the students have comprehended the previous session.   
           \end{tabitem}           \\ 
    \hline
    Magazine 
      &\makecell{Ali Ashraf \\ Ahmed Hamed} 
        & sdsdsdsds \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some simplifications and improvements for the vertical spacing, in particular for the lists, loading the `enumitem` and `makecell` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \setlist[itemize]{wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, topsep =3pt, after =\vspace*{\dimexpr\topsep-\baselineskip}}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c| m{3in}|}
        \hline
        Position & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Person(s)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Role} \\ \hline
        Co-head &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Islam Mahdy\\ Youssef Amr\end{tabular} &
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Reviewing the content of each session previously.
            \item Reviewing the progression of the academic sessions whether they for the Curriculum sessions or the standardized tests' sessions.
            \item Having continuous check on the magazine to ensure the conformity of the topics discussed to the club's goal
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        Vice head &
        Ahmed Magdy &
    loremipsum \\ \hline
        Head of Academics & Mohamed Badr & \begin{itemize}
            \item Preparing the content of each session.
            \item Managing the time table of the weekly-held sessions.
            \item Conducting mini quizzes each week to make sure the students have comprehended the previous session.
        \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Magazine} &
        \multirowcell{2}{Ali Ashraf \\ Ahmed Hamed} &
        \multirow{2}{*}{sdsdsdsds} \\
        & & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]